# How can the charged object move towards the reference charge , without acceleration while measuring the electric potential of a point?

Tags: electrostatics

It is given in the defination of electric potential in a website that we bring a charge from infinity to that point slowly(without acceleration). But if the charge placed at  infinity is at rest or moving towards a random direction then how can we place the the charge on the required point without acceleration. May be I have some misconception  , please clear my concept. I don't  have much information  so please help me out from this problem.

Comment: Can you link your source?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential

Comment: It is mentioned without producing an acceleration

Comment: I am still in a state of confusion ...Can anyone provide me a very clear and simple answer to help me out....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric Potential Energy - How a charge can be brought from infinity to a point without accelerating it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579974/electric-potential-energy-how-a-charge-can-be-brought-from-infinity-to-a-point)

Comment: While the linked duplicate is a newer question, I think the link above has more detail in the answer, so I think this should be marked as a duplicate with a link to the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

An external force is applied to the charge which varies so as not to change the speed of the charge.
That external force can change the direction of motion of the charge but not change its speed by acting in a direction which is at right angles to the direction of the velocity of the charge.
This would mean that the force does no work on the charge and hence does not change its speed even though the charge is accelerating because it is changing its direction of motion.

Comment: But what if charge placed at infinity is at rest....

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in its defination  given by wikipedia that "without producing an acceleration ".

Comment: Then how can we change the direction

Comment: If the charge is at rest to start with the force can do some work to get the charge moving and the do the same amount of negative work to stop the charge at the final position.

Comment: I think that the no acceleration probably refers refer to not changing the speed (and hence the kinetic energy).of the charge.

Comment: Can you please provide me a link from where I can get a clear idea about this defination....

Answer (score 0):

Obvious to move a charge from infinity without accelerating it is not a very practical proposal if the charges attract. You can also let it fall in, measure its speed and subtract the kinetic energy. For the repulsive case I see no issue other than that infinity is very far off.

Comment: Can you please explain it more deeply....if you have a better link to study from then please send.