# Electric Potential Energy - How a charge can be brought from infinity to a point without accelerating it?

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy

**Question:**

My Book says:

> **ELECTRIC POTENTIAL ENERGY:** Electric potential energy of a charge($q_o$) at a point(A) in the electric field due to any charge is given by the work done by an external force to displace $q_o$ without acceleration from infinity to that point(A).

$\color{red}{\text{How it is possible to displace a charge from infinity to a point without accelerating it}?}$

Suppose a point test charge q is located at:

(1) **Infinity**

> Then the moment an external force $F_{external}$, the charge gets accelerated.

(2)**A point in Q's electric field**

> Then the charge Q would exert an electrostatic force($F_Q$) and point charge q would accelerate due to this force. My book says now an external force $F_{external}$ is exerted to move it without any acceleration. *Book does not specifies which force is larger*.
>
> > Now three cases arrive:
> > $$(1) F_{external}>F_Q$$$$(2)F_{external}=F_Q$$ $$(3) F_{external}<F_Q$$
> > In (1) and (2) cases there would be some net force, so there would be acceleration.
> > In (3) case the net force would be zero so the charge would be at rest.

Comment: I can't grasp your question. There is a lot of back and forth between the question in book and question you have. I think this would be fixed if you could split up the stack exchange question into multiple segments.

Comment: I am not asking a question from book.

Comment: Note that this question has been asked before [here[(https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/499542/179151), but I think BobD's answer has more detail than the answers there, so I have linked to this one as a duplicate for that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is it possible to displace a charge from infinity to a point
> without accelerating it.

The statement in the book is somewhat misleading. Assuming the charge begins at rest at infinity, the requirement is to bring the charge to rest at the point so that the change in kinetic energy between the two points is zero.

To start the movement requires an acceleration over time (to achieve a velocity) and to stop the movement requires an equal deceleration over time (to bring the object to rest). In so doing the net work done on the object equals zero and the change in kinetic energy equals zero per the work energy theorem. All the work done by the external force winds up as stored electrical potential energy of the charge.

In terms of your three cases, the sequence is:

$$(1) F_{external}>F_Q$$

$$(2) F_{external}=F_Q$$

$$(3)F_{external}<F_Q$$

Where

$F_{external}$ of case (1) gives the charge a velocity $v$

$F_{external}$ of case (2) maintains the charge at velocity $v$

$F_{external}$ of case (3) brings the charge to rest $v=0$.

No work is done in case (2). The positive work done on the charge in case (1) equals the negative work done on the charge in case (3) for a net work of zero and an overall change in kinetic energy of zero.

Finally, note that as the difference between $F_{external}$ and $F_Q$ approaches zero the acceleration approaches zero, and it takes an infinite amount of time to bring the charge from infinity to the point.

The gravity analogy is taking a mass at rest and elevating the object to rest at height $h$ above its starting point.

> How the work done can be zero? $_{∞}=_{}−_{∞} = _{}−0=0$
> This shows that electric potential energy would always be 0.

I didn't say the work done by the external force is zero. I said the *net work* done by the combination of the external force and the force of the electric field is zero. The distinction is important. The net work has to be zero in order for the charge to begin and end at rest. The work in your equation is only the work done by the external agent. That does equal the change in electric potential energy as long as the electric field does an equal amount of negative work, otherwise the work done by the external force will equal the sum of the change in potential energy plus any change in kinetic energy equal to the net work done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How the work done can be zero?  $W_{\infty A}=U_B - U_{\infty}$ = $U_B-0$=0 This shows that electric potential energy would always be 0.

Comment: @Mayank You are confusing the work done by the external agent alone with the net work done by the combination of the external agent and the electric field. My answer refers to the net work being zero, not the work done by the external force alone,  in order for the charge to begin and end at rest. I have updated my answer to elaborate.

Comment: This question here is similar to (and possibly a duplicate of) [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/499542/179151), but I think your answer gives more detail than the answers there, so I have voted to close that question as a duplicate of this one. Just a heads up :)

Comment: @BioPhysicist Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Bob D “$F_{external}$ of case (2) maintains the charge at velocity v”
 Which case(2), your's sequence or mine?

Comment: @Mayank Mine, After the external force causes the charge to reach velocity $v$  in case (1), the external force is reduced to equal the electric field force so that the net force is zero and the charge continues on with constant velocity $v$.

Comment: @Bob D “In case 2 if $F_{External} = F_Q$, then the net force is be zero and there is no friction, So the charge moves with constant velocity”. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mayank Yes. It assumes no friction

Comment: @Bob D Can you give a more precise definition of electric potential energy?

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia article “Electric Potential Energy”

Comment: @Bob D Where the work done by electric field (to be precise electrostatic force by Q)go?

Comment: @Mayank Once more, the work done by the electrostatic force is negative work. The work done by the external force is positive work. Positive work transfers energy to the charge. Negative work takes that same energy away from the charge and stores it as electrical potential energy. It is analogous to gravity. When you (an external force) lifts an object .you do positive work giving the object energy. Gravity does an equal amount of negative work taking the energy you gave the object and stores it as gravitational potential energy.

Comment: Is $F_{external}$ constant?

Comment: Not for point charges. The closer the charges get the greater the attraction or repulsion force of the electric field and therefore the greater the external force has to be to overcome or equal the force of the field.

Comment: Why? As the object is reaching more dense electric field , Electrostatic force is also increasing. Even if it is constant. All 3 cases will satisfy

Comment: If an external field is moving a positive charge from infinity towards another fixed positive charge, can't you see that the closer the charge comes to the fixed charge the greater the repulsion force that has to be  equaled or exceeded in order to  maintain constant velocity or accelerate the charge?

Comment: How the charge would deaccelerate? I thought it would deaccelerate by the $F_{Q}$, and if $F_{External}$ is equal to $F_{Q}$ then the charge would not deaccelerate?                   *Pardon me if I am irritating you*

Comment: The electric field force  is constantly changing so the external force has to also constantly change to equal it to keep the velocity constant. It’s not that you’re irritating me, but I’m afraid you’re just not getting it and I have no more time to keep explaining the same thing over and over again. So with that I’m signing off.

Comment: And feel free to unaccept my answer if I can’t satisfy you

Comment: Thanks a lot :-). I won't unaccept your answer. I would have upvoted it if I have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

That wording is poor.  By definition, you can't take **any** object at rest and move it without imparting acceleration.

Further, since the electric field is a conservative field, the work needed to move the particle is both path- and acceleration- independent -- other, of course for the final velocity if you don't apply a "braking force" at the end of the journey.

Comment: Which definition?

Comment: @Mayank   The law of inertia.

Comment: If there is some acceleration, then there will be some change in kinetic energy. Then how potential energy formula can be derived?

Answer (score 0):

Only because $q_0$ is very far away, it doesn't mean that it must be at rest with respect to the point $A$. I can suppose that no matter how far I imagine $q_0$, it has a radial velocity $v$ in direction to $A$.

Suppose the charges have opposed signals. Some control device attached to $q_0$ makes sure that the increasing force due to decreasing distance is balanced by an equal force opposing to it. So, the net force on $q_0$ is always zero, and the work done can be thought be made by the eletrostatic force or the opposing force, because they are always equal in modulus.

Answer (score -1):

You can assume that in the beginning you have a very, very small acceleration  resulting in v, from then on you have no force so your last equation ist true, at the end you still have m/2v^2 left for your energy balance.

Comment: “Then on you have no force” Why? There is $F_{external}$ and  $F_Q$